# How to display </title> as title in html?

Tags: html, character-encoding, escaping

How can you set the title of a html page to `</title>`?

I already tried it with `&gt;` and `&lt;` but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say...

Comment: `<title>&lt;/title&gt;</title>` works fine for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a complete example:](http://jsbin.com/pefas/1/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&lt;/title&gt;</title>
    </head>
    <body>Foo bar</body>
</html>
```

It sounds like your attempt *should* have worked, but without sufficient code to reproduce no one's going to be able to do more than guess at what the problem was.

Comment: I nearly had the same, but without body. And the jsfiddle is not working for me. My browser still shows &lt;/title&gt;. But I think then it's an issue of my browser --.--

Comment: Firefox 26.0 - But recently I had a virus which has installed a total of 120 toolbars and plugins and so on. I have my system clean now, but it seems to be destroyed now :( So anyway, thanks for helping me, I#m going to reinstall my Windows now :/